# Add menu items to SHIFT + right click menu on Windows

Tags: windows, right-click, shell-extensions

The point is to add right click menu items *only* for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right click</kbd>. Don't even bother: regular right click is all over the web, but I want to add some items that wouldn't clutter my right click.

Here's how to add "Open Command Window Here" for right click menu. What do I need to modify to add it only to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right click</kbd>?

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt]
@="Open Command Window Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt\command]
@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

(Yes, I know, that's exactly what win7 does).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt]
@="Open Command Window Here"
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\CommandPrompt\command]
@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

Note the `"Extended"=""` command on the fourth line.

Answer (score 5):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\CommandPrompt]
@="Open Command Window Here"
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\CommandPrompt\command]
@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

You probably want to add to the Background

Comment: welcome to superuser, but as you can see the question had been answered half a year ago ;)

Comment: yea the answer wasn't working for me and once I changed the background one it seemed to work. I'm glad you asked this question because it was a good starting point.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me either, but this one did.

Answer (score 1):

While searching for solutions on how I can add the command to regular right click, i stumbled upon this question.
I already had the solution to open the command prompt window on shift+right click and I feel like I should share it, since it's a bit different than the ones mentioned here.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; show OpenCmdWindow when shift+right click
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
"HideBasedOnVelocityId"=-
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8
```

I also noticed that you need permissions for changing the values in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`. I use [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/feature-set/) to modify permissions from command line.

Answer (score 0):

1. In regedit go to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`
2. Go to your Key
3. Add a String and name it `Extended`

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.