# Way to open a folder from Windows Explorer in cmd.exe under Windows 10 with one shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, shortcuts

I'm looking for a shortcut kind of way in Windows 10 to open cmd.exe with a directory/folder from the Windows Explorer, so that I have this specific folder as actual working directory in the command prompt.

I know the trick with holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and **Right-Click** on the relative folder in Explorer, where you are getting an extra menu option for open it in cmd.exe, as explained here:

[How to open a terminal quickly from a file explorer at a folder in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/340051/1109379)

But unfortunately that does not work in Windows 10, it only works for Windows 7 and Windows 8. In Windows 10 you only have the option to open it in the PowerShell, but not in the command prompt / cmd.exe.

- How do I open a folder from Windows Explorer in cmd.exe without doing too much typing?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does PowerShell not work for you? It functions pretty much the same as Command Prompt.

Comment: Make it work like it did in W7>>>>https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/72024-open-command-window-here-add-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **does work** for Windows 10. There are already many duplicate questions:

- [How do I change "Open with Powershell" to "Open with Command Prompt" when shift-rightclicking in Explorer?](https://superuser.com/q/1201988/241386)
- [How to restore "Open command prompt" in Windows Explorer's File menu on Creators Update?](https://superuser.com/q/1206405/241386)
- ['Open command window here' does not appear in context menu](https://superuser.com/q/1279035/241386)

Basically just **take ownership** of the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd` key and **rename** the DWORD `HideBasedOnVelocityId` to `ShowBasedOnVelocityId`. For more details read

- [How to restore the “Open command window here” option in Build 14986 and newer](https://insidewindows.net/2016/12/15/how-to-restore-the-open-command-window-here-option-in-build-14986-and-newer/)
- [Restore “Open Command Window Here” Option in SHIFT+Right-Click Menu](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-restore-open-command-window-here-option-in-shiftright-click-menu/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=63098755851e37f3f61c846259b57baec91c5748-1579880756-0-AWNT285EAXoDXtoT6nNk__ADgpVuhkG90oKnamD9Hgw6JeRmXCGZv4MSKme5evc0uEg1XmriDUBld-kxa7kofndAoAoCIpQCdNkXD4TaIjVqpMfu847v-ZUIT2GYIYHPxB501aoV5A8vDOmnI0piXgIwI9j--5_mO8ORNfZtea6KKc-UHHRleT2Os_QV-qC86fghqmwZTfxm61XLJgtDGy-1_S2elEvhlIagLRuKeeTTkjaxtM-97FjYI4rRwr3jiPW9L0kcNmnP9N4zeC_lwpuXPcKRyn3hfJiNF6JSHUTpS2yT5QamM-wAHKDHGTFugcU8A1gG-eZNo8JwvGW-VZqKcSj813s8_Q4h5md0hPtjzhL_zWn-TyMwaxsjf53bhaB-q3pWwSkcvC0Sq3zjGeKsoxIlpt09f_DzV3yHEaI3)
- [Restore Open command window here item to Windows 10 folder context menu](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/restore-open-command-window-here-windows-10)
- [How to return the 'Open command window here' option to Windows 10's context menu](https://www.windowscentral.com/add-open-command-window-here-back-context-menu-windows-10)

You can also get the menu item ["Command Prompt Here" without shift key in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1077073/241386), or [Add menu items to SHIFT + right click menu on Windows](https://superuser.com/q/453658/241386)

---

Alternatively just use Andrew Richards' [Enhancing the “Open Command Prompt here” Context Menu experience](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andrew_richards/enhancing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shift-right-click-context-menu-experience) tweak and have the option to run cmd/powershell/bash... both as normal and elevated rights

[image: run cmd elevated]

[image: run powershell elevated]

Just import the below *.reg file (or copy from the MSDN blog above)

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Command Prompt

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt Elevated"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""


; PowerShell

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Elevated"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"


; Ensure OS Entries are on the Extended Menu (Shift-Right Click)

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\cmd]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell]
"Extended"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background\shell\Powershell]
"Extended"=""
```

Comment: That´s a great collection of data to that topic. TYVM.

Comment: For completeness, you might want to add to `HKCR\Drive` as well... :D

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to go to the address bar*, or click in it and make sure everything is selected (it should be by default). Alternatively, [user phuclv informs us](https://superuser.com/questions/1519562/way-to-open-a-folder-from-windows-explorer-in-cmd-exe-under-windows-10-with-one/1519563#comment2301192_1519563) that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> also selects the address bar.

Type `cmd` and press Enter.

---

You can do the same to get a PowerShell window, just type `powershell` instead of `cmd`.

---

* [Microsoft: Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: I don´t get into the address bar after pressing Alt + D. Instead I get into the "File" menu. Also, how does that open a specific folder in cmd.exe?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica In that case, click in the address bar. When the command prompt window opens, it will be in the directory that was showing in the main pane.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica - By default PowerShell and the command prompt directory will initialize at that directory.  I can confirm that the shortcut works as expected, it should not expand the File menu, but without specific information about the system I can't investigate the possible reasons it's not working for you.

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 Home, Version 1809, x64.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica If Alt-D got you to the file menu, perhaps you let go of Alt before pressing D. That's the only way I can get it behave like that.

Comment: if `Alt+D` doesn't bring you to the address bar then probably you're not using English Windows. Use `Ctrl+L` instead. Another workaround is to press `F4` although the behavior is not exactly the same

Comment: @phuclv Yes, it has worked with `Ctrl + L`. The source because of `Alt + D` does not work at my system is exactly the same as you said, I got a PC with german Windows distribution on it. Cool trick.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica The corresponding MS help in German - [Tastaturkurzbefehle in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts) - says Alt+D. Perhaps you would like to add something to the "An Diskussion teilnehmen" section at the end of that page to tell them it doesn't work. My German is inadequate for that.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I like this trick because its so simple to achieve. Can I open CMD with the focused folder as administrator in this way, too?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica I don't think so. I tried with ctrl+shift+enter, which would run it as Administrator from the windowskey+R box, but that didn't do anything useful.

Comment: best answer and better than messing with the registry imo

Answer (score 1):

You may use the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Here is a script that will start the Command Prompt on the current folder
in Explorer when <kbd>F12</kbd> is clicked.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
~F12::
    ControlGetText, _Path, toolbarwindow322, ahk_class CabinetWClass
    StringReplace, _Path, _Path,% "Address: ",% ""
    Run %comspec%, %_Path%
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

For choosing another hotkey than <kbd>F12</kbd>, see AutoHotkey
[List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly copied from quick reference : [add-open-command-window-here-windows-10-context-menu by editing registry keys](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/add-open-command-window-here-windows-10-context-menu)

**Adding ‘Open command window here’ Option to the Windows 10 Context Menu of a Folder**

> Step One: Press Windows key and + R from the keyboard to open the Run
>   command. Type regedit and then hit enter from the keyboard to open the
>   registry.
>
> Step Two: Go to the following path:
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd
>
> Right-click the cmd key. Scroll to Permissions and then click it.
>
> Step Three: Click Advanced.
>
> Step Four: Click the Change link.
>
> Step Five: Type your user account name and click ‘Check Names’ to
>   verify it. Click OK when you are done.
>
> Step Six: Check ‘Replace owner on subcontainers and objects’. Click
>   Apply and then OK.
>
> Step Seven: In ‘Permissions for cmd’ window, select the Administrator
>   account. Check Allow for full control option. Click Apply and then OK.
>
> Step Eight: Inside the cmd key (right window), right click
>   HideBasedOnVelocityId and then click Rename.
>
> Step Nine: Rename the DWORD from HideBasedOnVelocityId to
>   ShowBasedOnVelocityId, then hit Enter from the keyboard.
>
> You are done. When you press shift from the keyboard and then
>   right-click on any folder, you will have the ‘Open command window
>   here’ option on the Windows 10 Context Menu.

**Adding ‘Open command window here’ Option to the Context Menu of Background**

> Here are the few steps you need to take:
>
> Step One: Press Windows key + R simultaneously to open the Run
>   command. Type regedit and hit enter from the keyboard to open the
>   registry.
>
> Step Two: Go to the following path:
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd
>
> Step Three: Right-click the cmd key and then click Permissions.
>
> Step Four: Click Advanced.
>
> Step Five: Click the change link on top of the window in front of
>   owner option.
>
> Step Six: Type your user account name and click ‘Check Names’ to
>   verify it. Click OK when you are done.
>
> Step Seven: Check ‘Replace owner on subcontainers and objects’ option.
>   Click Apply and then OK.
>
> Step Eight: In permissions window, choose the administrator user.
>   Check Allow for Full Control option, click Apply and then OK.
>
> Step Nine: Inside the cmd key (right window), right-click the
>   HideBasedOnVelocityId DWORD and then click Rename.
>
> Step Ten: Change the DWORD name from HideBasedOnVelocityId to
>   ShowBasedOnVelocityId and press Enter from the keyboard.
>
> That’s all. When you press shift and right-click anywhere on your
>   windows background, you will have an option of ‘Open command window
>   here’ as shown in the following screenshot from Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

- So, save this code as file.**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**, and run or click **(need admin rights)**.

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00;Command Prompt Here[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]@="Command Prompt Here"[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
  cls & echo/ & "%__APPDIR__%reg.exe" import "%~f0" & "%__APPDIR__%timeout" -1
  ```
- This is the reg part of hybrid with **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
  @="Command Prompt Here"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
  @="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
  ```
- You get this menu context: **`Command Prompt Here`**
- You don't need additional startup script or holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and **Right-Click**.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on desktop, add shortcut and write this as target:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k " cd\ & cd "C:\ThePath\ToOpenCMDin"
```